# Azure Consumer Group From Settings File

Tags: c#, azure-functions

For a C# azure function, we wish to re-use the same function with only a single change which is the target consumer group. Ideally we could set the consumer group in an environmental variable that is loaded through local.settings.json. However, these settings are not read in as constants. The consumer group must be constant in order to comiple.

How does one load in a consumer group from a settings file?

Comment: Hi Nathan, could you share relevant code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `function.json` file you can specify consumer group name inside `%` symbol:

```
{
    ...
    "consumerGroup": "%groupname%"
    ...
}
```

and then add an Application setting with corresponding name (`groupname` in this case). Consumer group will then be resolved to the setting name at startup.

Of course, you can do the same if you use precompiled .NET functions:

```
[EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", 
                                      ConsumerGroup = "%groupname%")]
```

Comment: function.json is generated by Visual studios, to my knowledge it is not to be manually edited?
Regarding Application setting, these don't exist for class libraries which a C# azure function is. 
Regarding %variable% and a pre-compile, not sure how to get that to work.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it to work. Its somewhat tricky to validate that one is indeed connected to the correct consumer group.