# azure function not able to read consumer group name from appsettings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

i am using event hub trigger in azure function

```
public static class DbuTask
{
    [FunctionName("DbuTask")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("EventHubEntity", Connection = "EventHubConnection",ConsumerGroup = "consumergroup")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
```

my local.setting.json entry for consumergroup

```
"consumergroup": "DbuTask",
```

Comment: Do you encounter this locally or when you published it to Azure?

Comment: in both the cases its not working

Comment: I don't think that this setting is actually resolved from the appsettings. I believe this one is actually "taken as is". I.e. it tries to find a consumer group called "consumergroup"

Comment: yes..can you please help to take it from app setting , as we can not hard code it like  this

Comment: try the following: ConsumerGroup = "%consumergroup%"

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031181/azure-consumer-group-from-settings-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Roman and tony said, use `ConsumerGroup = "%ConfigurationConsumerGroup%"` to read settings from `local.settings.json`. Check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings).

**Note**: The connection property of triggers and bindings is a special case and automatically resolves values as app settings, without percent signs.

Comment: Documentation is located over here: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings)